# iFrame Cross-Domain Tracking via GTM

Tags: google-analytics, cross-domain, google-tag-manager

My client's site contains a donation form (https://www.resurge.org/donate/) which is an embedded iframe from a 3rd-party provider. I have separate GTM containers installed on the main domain and in the iframe page, and want to pass the original clientId to the iFrame. On the parent page, I have the following code:

```
<script>
setTimeout(function(){ 
  ga(function(tracker) {
    var clientId = tracker.get('clientId');
    var frameWindow = document.getElementById('my_iframe').contentWindow;
    // change https://xyz.shoppingcart.com to match your iFrame domain
    frameWindow.postMessage(clientId, 'https://app.etapestry.com'); 
  });
}, 2000); 
</script>
```

and in the iFrame:

```
<script>
  window.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
    // Ignores messages from untrusted domains.
    if (event.origin != 'https://www.resurge.org') return;
    // Creates the tracker with the data from the parent page.
    ga('create', 'UA-19540393-1', 'auto', {clientId: event.data});
    ga('send', 'pageview');
  });
</script>
```

GA Debugger shows the following results:

```
Running command: ga("create", "UA-19540393-1", {name: "gtm2", allowLinker: true, cookieDomain: "auto"})   
  Creating new tracker: gtm2 
  Auto cookieDomain found: "etapestry.com" 
Running command: ga("gtm2.set", "&gtm", "2wg1r0WMV887L") 
Running command: ga("gtm2.set", "hitCallback", [function])
```

I'd expect to see the original clientId after `cookieDomain: "auto"`. Not sure what I'm missing here.

Comment: GA Debugger output you're seeing looks like a log of Google Analytics tag installed within Google Tag Manager. Make sure that an iframe do really contain a message listener and that `ga` object is defined at the moment when a listener is called. Probably you'll need to add basic analytics snippet to define a `ga` object before referencing `ga` in a listener

Comment: Confirmed that the event listener runs in the iframe after the `ga` object is created. 

I had an exception running on the parent page which prevented the GA tag from running. With that resolved, my GA debug console shows: `Running command: ga("create", "UA-19540393-1", "auto", {clientId: "[iFrameSizer]my_iframe:8:false:true:32:false:true:null:offset:null:null:0:false:parent"})`

This now looks like an issue with iframe-resizer.js. I'll follow up on their github page.